# android Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS Or android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS

Tags: android

I'm confused between Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS and android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS.

In the manifest.xml I use:
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"

However the runtime request I use:

```
intPerm  = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS);
        if (intPerm != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS},
                    10);
        }
```

Why the difference?

Answer (score 3):

> Why the difference?

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#RECEIVE_SMS

`"android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"` is a literal string.

`Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS` is a `String` object whose *value* is `"android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"`

In your manifest you require a string literal. In code it's best to use a constant instead of hard-coding.